# How to set div height depending on screen height minus the height of an absolutely positioned element?

Tags: css

I have a panel with a height of 100vh, so 100% of the screen (but height: 100% doesn't work, for some reason).

This panel must show a div with its own contents and the footer.

The footer is normally displayed under that panel, but in the front page it must be inside it, so I have to disable the normal one and call it inside the panel.
Thus, it must have position: absolute and bottom: 0.

Now the problem is that the footer takes its own height (which changes a bit when resizing the window's width), and the other div in the panel must take all the remaining height.

So, is there a way to set that div's height dynamically, rather than filling the CSS with media queries for each window width where the footer's height changes, setting it as height: calc(100vh - [footer height])?

Comment: Could you provide code or a fiddle that we can test with? Makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Basically, NO...not without javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you don't set height for parent elements, setting height in percentages on the child won't work. Your parent elements should have their height set to 100% (including html and body elements).

Secondly, if your browser support is IE10+, I recommend using flexboxes.
Here's how you do it (without browser prefixes):

```
.parent-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

This will set the parent container as flexbox and change its direction to "column" (so its children stack one under the other).

```
.expanding-child {
    height: 100%;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This is the wrapper for your content. It will expand as much as it can, keeping in mind your footer's height.

```
.sticky-child {
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
}
```

This is your footer that will now always be at the bottom, pinned, without overlapping the scrollable content.

Here is what your HTML would look like:

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="expanding-child">
    </div>

    <div class="sticky-child">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I made a quick fiddle to demonstrate it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5efzqzp8/)

This will work as intended only if **you set height to 100% on all parent elements**.

Edit: [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css3-flexible-box-layouts.php) is a good source to learn more about flexbox, I recommend looking into it. And [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is one I used when I first started using flexbox.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking about sticky footer. I hope it will helps you. Always footer fixed at bottom using `FlexBox` 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/balatamizh/av4bnacp/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes